# sed removes some but not all double quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I have a directory filled 64 large tsv files (200 million+ rows in total). They contain some text fields and I need to remove all the `"` from the text since it interferes with the database ingestion. so I ran the following command:

`for FILE in *; do cat $FILE | sed 's/"//g' > /my/file/path/$FILE; done`

This removed almost all the `"` but there are 123 rows that all still getting flagged. Here is an example of a row that is being logged as still containing a double quote character:

```
2199180165  22362           alguien por casualidad quiere decir algo reflexiones sobre las interpretaciones de los silencios en programas de inclusion para jovenes "¿Alguien por casualidad quiere decir algo? Reflexiones sobre las interpretaciones de los silencios en programas de inclusión para jóvenes      2015    2015-04-01      Consejo General de Colegios de Diplomados en Trabajo Social                 107 101 114 0   1   1   Servicios sociales y política social            2016-06-24"
```

What is is about this row that is stopping sed from removing the double quotes? How can I change my regular expression to remove these characters?

Comment: Are those rows located in a specific part of the file, or they are randomly scattered around?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they're just randomly scattered thoughout

Comment: not sure if it has anything to do with the locale but you can try `export LC_ALL=C` before invoking `sed`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me, `sed` removes the `"` at the end. If `LC_ALL=C` doesn't work, you could try `tr -d \" < file` next.

Answer (score 0):

What is your working directory in ...

> `for FILE in *; do cat $FILE | sed 's/"//g' > /my/file/path/$FILE; done`

... ? If it is  `/my/file/path/` you might mangle the file because reading and writing the same file at the same time has all kind of problems. That could explain why some `"` are deleted while others are not.

To fix this problem, you can use a temporary file or `sed`'s in-place option `-i`. The later also makes the loop uneccesary.

```
sed -i 's/"//g' *
```

If that doesn't work, try `LC_ALL=C tr -d \" < file` as written in the comments.